# How to calculate normal inverse cumulative distribution function efficiently in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using `norm.ppf()` in Python to calculate normal inverse cumulative distribution, but I found it is much slower than the `norminv()` in Matlab.

```
for i in range(10000):
    iri_next = norm.ppf(0.4, loc=0, scale=0.06)
```

cost about 2 seconds in Python, whereas

```
for i=1:10000
    IRI_next=norminv(0.4,0,0.06);
end
```

cost about 0.6 second in Matlab

Is there an efficient way to calculate normal inverse cumulative distribution in Python?

Comment: One small suggestion is to use python to call a c function i don't believe python will ever reach the same speeds of matlabs due to the underlying engine being done in c/c++

Comment: Why call the function 10000 times if the returned value is always the same?

Comment: Are you really measuring the differences in `ppf` and `norminv`, or just the difference between a Python loop and a Matlab loop?  Try some other operation in the loop, maybe even a "no op" (i.e. `pass` in Python) to check.

Comment: For example, try timing `for i in range(10000): pass` in Python and `for i=1:10000; end` in Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the fact that calling the function 10000 times with the same values will give you 10000 times the same returned value, you can pass an array as your first argument and get 10000 values all at once

```
scipy.stats.norm.ppf(numpy.full(10000, 0.4), loc=0, scale=0.06)
```

in 0.006 seconds on my machine